# Converting a comma separated string to array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, delimiter

I have been trying to convert a string in array of integers, floats and characters. While I could get it work for integers and floats, there is some problem for characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *s1;
    int k, no=5;
    char* variable = "R1,R2,R3,R4,R5";
    void* value;

    s1 = calloc(no,sizeof(char)*81);
    for (k=0; k<no; k++) s1[k] = strdup(mchar);
    ListChar(variable, s1, no, ",");
    memcpy(value, s1, no*sizeof(char)*81);
    free(s1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        printf("%s", value[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the header file I have

```
#define mchar "A...(81times)"
```

Implementation:

```
int ListChar(char *buf, char *list, int maxloop, char* delim)
{
    int n = 0;
    char *s,*t;
    s= strdup(buf);
    t= strtok(s,delim);
    while ( t && (n<maxloop))
    {
        if (list!=NULL) list[n] =strdup(t);
        n++;
        t=strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    free(s);
    return(n);
}
```

During the calloc memory assignment when I watch `s1` its `0xsomeadress ""`
After the for loop `s1` becomes `0xsomeadress "Garbage value 81 times"`
When `s1` is assigned to `list` its still reads the same garbage value.
And when `list [n] = strdup(t)` `list[0]` reads the first block of garbage value like `-21 '\221 ṗ'`.

`t` is getting delimited correctly. I even tried initializing `char *s1[81] = {"something"}` and looping it on `j` but it wont work, same problem, and I need to free `s1` at the end because this function runs for number of times. I did it for integers and floats by `list[n]=atoi(t)` it works fine. Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: And be sure to reserve space for the required terminating `'\0'`s

Comment: If you're calling `calloc` with an uninitialized `no`, the result could be anything. `strdup` returns a `char *` which you are assigning into `s1[k]` which is a `char` and will then look like random garbage (as pointer values viewed as integers often do). Try enabling compiler warnings and fix them all before proceeding.

Comment: How do you know this fails? There are no printouts. Please construct a [mre]

Comment: If you don't see an error message for `s1[k] = strdup(mchar);` then change your compiler settings, as you are wasting time trying to run incorrect code

Comment: Hi all, sorry there was typo in the define, also @klutt I have made my code reproducible as earlier it was just a snippet

Comment: @dratenik Sorry the code was a snippet of a bigger code. `no` has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding about how strings work.  Your  `s1` clearly needs to be a `char **` and the usage of `strdup` is incorrect.  If `s1` is of type `char *`, then `s1[k]` is of type `char`.  But `strdup` returns a `char *`, so `s1[k] = strdup ...` is clearly an error which your compiler ought to warn you about.  Perhaps you want something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * xmalloc(size_t s);

void
ListChar(const char *buf, char **list, int maxloop, int delim)
{
    char set[] = {delim, 0};
    for( int n = 0; n < maxloop; n += 1 ){
        size_t len = strcspn(buf, set);
        list[n] = xmalloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(list[n], buf, len);
        buf += len + 1;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int delim = ',';
    (void)argc; /* Suppress compiler warning */
    while( *++argv ){
        char **s1;
        int k, num = 1;
        char *input = *argv;
        for( const char *p = input; *p; p += 1 ){
            if( *p == delim ){
                num += 1;
            }
        }
        s1 = xmalloc(num * sizeof *s1);
        ListChar(input, s1, num, delim);
        for( int i = 0; i < num; i += 1 ){
            printf("%s\n", s1[i]);
        }
        free(s1);
    }
    return 0;
}


void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *rv = malloc(s);
    if( rv == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Note that the above code scans each string twice, which is not ideal. Rather than scanning the string to find the number of delimiters and then parsing the string, it would be better to do both in one pass.  But for the purposes of demonstrating how to break up the string, that seems like unnecessary complexity.  (Though it's actually simpler, IMO)

Comment: It works like a charm till `s1`, however instead of printing I want to copy `s1` to another `void* realvalue`. `realvalue` is a value linked to another header file values where all char are defined at a fixed size of 81. So if my input is `m_item` which is "A1,A2,A3,A4,A8,A9", I tried to assign `s1` to `realvalue` to `item[40][81]` by `memcpy(realvalue, s1, size of *s1)`. I cannot watch `realvalue` as its an attempt to derefence a generic pointer. However when I watch `item` at the end of the code it shows me some garbage value at [0], [1] & till [2] only. But my `num`/`maxloop` is set to 40.

Comment: On further check `list[n]` is also copying some garbage values. Eg. if `len` = 21 `list[1]` = "21correctcharacters\210","<<"<repeats 16 times>,"ibibibibib"